# On behalf of one of our customers: is there a publishing company out there that uses CivICRM?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, community

Our customer Acquire Publishing is starting on their CiviCRM road with attached websites, memberships, events and all sorts of stuff......They are wondering if there are any other publishing organizations in the CiviCRM community so they can exchange how stuff is done, share success stories and perhaps do some development together?

Answer (score 1):

[The New Press](https://thenewpress.com/) uses CiviCRM. There's also a magazine publisher (I forget offhand who) who uses CiviCRM and was exploring development to better handle magazine subscriptions in CiviCRM.

Comment: Thanks Jon, will pass it on!

Answer (score 1):

The Monthly - a magazine in Australia - maybe the one Jon is thinking of. We worked with them 7 years ago to help set up their Subscription process, and are reworking this for them currently.

Pioneers Post - a social enterprise magazine - is another Fuzion client that uses civicrm for its Subscriptions system.

Neither are what I would consider a 'publishing company' though.

Comment: Thanks Pete, will pass it on and entice them to join Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[Cristianisme i Justícia](https://www.cristianismeijusticia.net/en) is a study center dedicated to reflecting on social and theological issues. Dissemination of its findings through courses, conferences, social networks, and especially its booklets, which are sent out to more than 45,000 persons around the world. We have been using CiviCRM for 5 years now.

Comment: thanks for sharing!